# Interpreting a zero when reading data from the serial line in MATLAB using 'fscanf'

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino, scanf, null-terminated

I have a stream of data coming in over the serial line from an Arduino board. The stream looks like this:

```
0x43 0x03 0x39 0x00 0x0D 0x0A
```

The first two bytes (0x43 and 0x03) are single-byte integer values. The next two bytes (0x39 and 0x00) are a single 16-bit little-endian signed integer value. The final two bytes (0x10 and 0x13) are supposed to be a terminator sequence ("\r\n").

I am using MATLAB to read in this data. I create a serial connection, open it, and read in the data. Unfortunately, I am running into problems with using 0x00 as a byte value because **fscanf** simply considers it to be the null-terminator of a string.

Here is some sample code:

```
%Create and open serial connection
serialcon = serial('COM5');
fopen(serialcon);

firstChar = fscanf(serialcon, '%c', 1); %Read 0x43
secondChar = fscanf(serialcon, '%c', 1); %Read 0x03
integerByteChars = fscanf(serialcon, '%c', 2); %Read 0x39 and 0x00
fscanf(serialcon, '%c'); %Read until end-of-line

integerBytes = uint8(integerByteChars); %value should be (in hex): [ 0x39 0x00 ]
integerValue = typecast(integerBytes, 'uint16'); %value should be (in hex): 0x0039
```

Unfortunately, what happens is "integerByteChars" is not a 2-element array as I would like it to be, but rather a 1-element array because `fscanf` just considers 0x00 to be a null-terminating string value. This surprises me, however, because I am inputting the data using '%c' and not '%s' (which is used for strings).

What I need is a function that will read these bytes as data even if it's a zero byte and not throw it away. What functions are available to me that will do that? Can [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html?nocookie=true) be coerced into doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fread would be a good way of doing this.

You could read all 6 bytes with:

```
 data = fread(s2,6,'uint8')
```

and then work through the vector that is returned.

```
 firstChar = data(1);
 secondChar = data(2);
 integerValue = data(3) + data(4) * 256;  % Need to check endian calc
 if data(5) ~= 13 || data(6) ~= 10
    error('Not terminated correctly')
 end
```

BTW, are you sure you have your CR/LF ASCII values correct?

Comment: Oops, yes, I accidentally put the decimal values for the CR/LF bytes instead of the hex values.  I have edited my original post to use the correct hex values.  Thanks for noticing that.